# Database problems with Heroku/Django: won't keep information after every push

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-models

Every time I make a change to the database in production on Heroku and then I do a push the database gets reset to whatever is on my local computer.  I have tried adding `db.sqlite3` and `__pycache__` to the `.gitignore`, but that doesn't work.

Does anyone know what to do with this problem?

**Update** (Changed the settings to) :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'thesite'),
        'USER': 'tom',
        'PASSWORD': '!'
    }
}
```

And added

```
import os
import psycopg2

DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']

conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')

import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Heroku's filesystem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem): any changes you make to files will be lost the next time your dyno restarts, which [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day). Since SQLite is a file-based database it is incompatible with Heroku.

You can use a client-server database instead. Heroku's own [PostgreSQL add-on](https://www.heroku.com/postgres) should be already set up for you, but you can use any of [several others](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/) if you prefer.

[`dj-database-url`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/dj-database-url) can simplify this for you: it lets you set your database configuration up from the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable, which should already be set up by Heroku Postgres.

Here's an example of how to use `dj-database-url` to use the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable if it's present and fall back to another database if it isn't:

```
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(default='sqlite://db.sqlite3')
```

I've shown an example that falls back to SQLite, but in reality I *strongy* recommend using the same database engine in all of your environments. Django's ORM helps "even out" different database engines, but there are still differences. You don't want to be in a position where your code works locally with SQLite, but fails in production with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Will I have to change DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

Comment: Ok, I am going to update my stuff.  Cause I changed it and now it's not accepting my username password on the admin

Comment: @lakerskill, well it's an entirely different database. You'll need to create a new superuser, e.g. via `heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser`. Your data won't sync between your local machine and production (normally that's okay).

Comment: Ok, so I'm able to log in now, will try a push with new info after creatign a couple of things

Comment: And you fixed it.  Thank you sir.  Marked as answered.  One quick question, if I add to the db locally, like another table or column or row, will that go straight to heroku with apush?  Like, if I add through models.py

Comment: @lakerskill, no. You'll have to run your migrations in each environment. Again, `heroku run` is your friend here. You could also set that up as a [release command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase) to have it run automatically on every push.

Comment: Funny, already had it done.  You just need the migrate command, not makemigrations?

Comment: `makemigrations` generates migration files based on changes to your models. Those migration files should be generated locally and committed to your repository. On other environments you don't need to generate the files again; just run `migrate` to apply them to your database.